# How to modify template html content that is rendering through Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to Angular Js, I am using a directive to render some HTML content on my index page

```
App.directive('header', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/assets/shared/header.html'
  };
});
```

And I am using this on my index page like this

```
<div header></div>
<div>#Other HTML</div>
```

It works fine and I am able to see my header on index page but after this when I modify some content on my 'header.html' then the my new changes are not appearing on index page header
Can any one help me what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you clear your browsers cache?

Comment: yeah, html contents are cached most oftenly and do not get refreshed on simple reload, you need hard reload by clearing browser cashe.